# Evaluating expressions with indexicals in SICStus Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to write a predicate in SICStus Prolog such that given an expression, I can evaluate it (possible several times).  The following works as expected:

```
?- A is 1, H = A+2+2, C is H.
C = 5 ?
yes
```

And so does this more elaborate code:

```
testing(Variables, Updates, Values, Result):-
    assert(temp(Variables, Updates)),
    temp(Values, Result),
    abolish(temp/2).

evaluate([],[]).
evaluate([Term|T1],[H|T2]):-
    H is Term,
    evaluate(T1,T2).
```

Now, if instead A is an indexical, say A in 1..3, it doesn't work anymore.  Any ideas about how to fix it?

The longer code is supposed to be used as follows:

```
?- testing([A,B,C], [A+1,B+C,max(A,B)], [0,0,0], Result), evaluate(Result, R).
Result = [0+1,0+0,max(0,0)],
R = [1,0,0] ? 
yes
```

But is suffers from the same problem as the small example: I can't provide ranges of values in this way:

```
?- Val1 in 1..2, Val2 in 3..10, testing([A,B], [A+1,B+A], [Val1,Val2], Result), evaluate(Result, R).
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that you are talking about indexicals which is quite specific to SICStus. But then, you use `(in)/2` which is present in many other systems,

Comment: `evaluate(Terms, Hs) :- maplist(is, Hs, Terms).`

Comment: `testing(Variables, Updates, Values, Result) :- copy_term(Variables-Updates, Values-Result).`

Comment: I just tested your suggestion for testing/4 and evaluate/2 and it also suffers from my original issue, meaning X in 1..3, testing_1([A,B], [A+1,B], [X,0], R), evaluate_1(R,R1). doesn't work.  I'll post below my current solution, which works but doesn't make me too happy.  I believe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Never claimed that the **entire** program works (you have not even responded to my initial remark for that). Quite the contrary: *both* are equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SICStus Prolog, and the context in which I'm using this code works with indexicals.

Comment: ... and you do not use a single indexical in your example?!?

Answer (score 1):

My current solution requires replacing is/2 with val_of/2.  It works, but I still believe there should be a better/faster implementation.

```
testing(Variables, Updates, Values, Result):-
    assert(temp(Variables, Updates)),
    temp(Values, Result),
    abolish(temp/2).

evaluate([],[]).

evaluate([Term|T1],[H|T2]):-
    val_of(H,Term),
    evaluate(T1,T2).


val_of(E,E):- number(E),!.
val_of(E,E):- var(E),!.
val_of(V,E1+E2):- !, val_of(V1,E1), val_of(V2,E2), V #= V1+V2.
val_of(V,E1-E2):- !, val_of(V1,E1), val_of(V2,E2), V #= V1-V2.
val_of(V,max(E1,E2)):- !, val_of(V1,E1), val_of(V2,E2), V #= max(V1,V2).
val_of(V,min(E1,E2)):- !, val_of(V1,E1), val_of(V2,E2), V #= min(V1,V2).
val_of(V,abs(E1,E2)):- !, val_of(V1,E1), val_of(V2,E2), V #= abs(V1,V2).
```

A test example:

```
| ?- X in 1..3, testing([A,B], [A+1,B], [X,0], R), evaluate(R,R1).
R = [X+1,0],
R1 = [_A,0],
X in 1..3,
_A in 2..4 ? 
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that all you need is just

```
evaluate([],[]).
evaluate([Term|T1],[H|T2]):-
    H #= Term,
    evaluate(T1,T2).
```

but the temp/2 relation is unnecessary, so a real simplification could be:

```
testing(Variables, Updates, Values, Result):-
  maplist(#=, Updates, Values), Result=Variables.
```

results in

```
?- testing([A,B,C], [A+1,B+C,max(A,B)], [0,0,0], Result).
A = -1,
B = C, C = 0,
Result = [-1, 0, 0].
```

(note: tested in SWI-Prolog, after `?- [library(clpfd)].`)

Comment: That does not work in SICStus, since in SICStus, `H #= Term` is tantamount to `#(H) #= #(Term)`. You need to wrap `call/1` around: So use `call(H #= Term)` in stead.

Comment: ... however, your version with `maplist/3` works for this very reason.

Comment: @CapelliC thank you for your answer.  Your testing/4 predicate doesn't work as I intended because it actually binds Variables so it doesn't give the expected results.

Comment: @false thanks! What I was missing was the call/1 in evaluate!

Comment: Try `call(#=, X, Term)` instead. It should be even faster, as it avoids the creation of `(#=)/2` on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

My final solution is a modified version of my original code based on the useful answers and comments provided by @CapelliC and @false:

```
testing(Variables, Updates, Values, Result):-
    copy_term(Variables-Updates, Values-Result).

evaluate([],[]).
evaluate([Term|T1],[H|T2]):-
    call(H #= Term),
    evaluate(T1,T2).
```

The main issue in my original code was the missing call/1 in evaluate/2.

A test example in SICStus Prolog looks like this:

```
?- A in 1..3, testing([C,D,R],[C+1,max(D,5),R],[A,0,0],Res), evaluate(Res,T).
Res = [A+1,max(0,5),0],
T = [_A,5,0],
A in 1..3,
_A in 2..4 ? 
yes
```